# Can an object literal be used as a pipe parameter?

Tags: angular, typescript, literals, string-interpolation, angular-pipe

I wrote a pipe that takes an object as a parameter:

```
@Pipe({name: "myPipe"})
export class MyPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform (value: string, options: any): string {
        // do stuff with value and options here
    }
}
```

It works fine when I use a variable for `options`:

```
<!-- this works fine -->
{{someString | myPipe: someObject}}
```

But if I try to use a literal instead:

```
<!-- this doesn't work -->
{{someString | myPipe: {foo: "bar"}}}
```

I get an amusingly repetitive error in the console:

> ERROR Error: "[object Object]"

I assume it's because the object literal doesn't play nice with the interpolation, but I'm not sure how else to write it.  Is there a way to accomplish this without having to add a bunch of extra variables to my TypeScript?

Comment: There's an existing bug, mentions a workaround of using parentheses: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9571

Comment: @jonrsharpe Must have missed that when I was searching somehow, but it solved the problem so go ahead and post it as an answer if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Via [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9571)

It works if you wrap the whole expression in parentheses:

```
<!-- this works -->
{{(someString | myPipe: {foo: "bar"})}}
```

Or if you add a space before the last two braces:

```
<!-- this also works -->
{{someString | myPipe: {foo: "bar"} }}
```